# How to add a plugin instead of a gem to a project? updates via git?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to try adding a library via a plugin instead of a gem.

How do you do that?  What are some tips on keep this up-to-date?

Do you just go to the plugins folder and pull the code in via GIT?  I don't want git related files in there, or is that best-practise?

Do I have to wire in the plugin somehow also?

```
e.g. instead of doing gem 'devise' in my Gemfile, I want it in /plugins/devise
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is for rails 2.3.x as I'm not sure how to do it in 3.

You can use `./script/plugin` to install plugins.

```
./script/plugin install git://github.com/plataformatec/devise.git
```

To keep it up to date, you can run `./script/plugin update` which updates all of your plugins. I'm not sure if you can specify a specific plugin. For a bit more info, just run `./script/plugin help`.

I'm also not sure if there's anything special that would need to happen to have devise work as a plugin versus a gem, but normally it-should-just-work™.

Comment: The Rails 3 syntax is `rails plugin install <plugin-url>`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the library will work as a plugin, call `./script/plugin install git://blahblah blah`.